# GetWindowRect returns wrong value if the window is near bottom right

Tags: c#, winapi

I am trying to get a windows position by it's handle. Then I want to draw a cross at the windows 0, 0 position like so (notepad is near the top-left of the display):

[image: how it should look]

but if I move notepad near the bottom right it looks like this:

[image]

That's totally weird for me.
I've logged the values of rect.Left and rect.Top and compared them with the values of Spy++, they were the same.

What i've tried:
from user32.dll:

```
GetWindowRect(handle, out var rect);
```

from dwmapi.dll:

```
DwmGetWindowAttribute(handle, DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE.ExtendedFrameBounds, out var rect, size);
```

That worked a bit better, but still the same behaviour.

Someone knows a way to find the windows 0, 0 independently where the window is?

Comment: Can we see the code where you draw the cross? And the actual numeric values from the rect in both of the cases shown?

Comment: What is the DPI awareness level of your program?

Comment: Here is the whole code https://pastebin.com/pzrufqaR (sorry its a bit unstructured but i think you can see how its drawn)

The important part is in the Render method.

Its drawn on a transparent windows form (
settings: BackColor: Black, 
FormBorderStyle: None, 
ShowIcon: false, 
ShowInTaskBar: false, 
TopMost: true, 
WindowState: Maximized)

Comment: GetWindowRect() tells a lot of appcompat lies.  Start by declaring your app [to be dpiAware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034).  Consider GetClientRect().  And consider to never need to do this.

Comment: Okay it seems like it has nothing todo with GetWindowRect.
when i draw with GDI on the Desktop (GetDC(IntPtr.Zero)) the cross fits perfectly on the top left corner.
So it has something todo with directX drawing on a transparent fullscreen form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the Problem myself. i had to set the FormWindowState back to Normal and FormBorderStyle to None but not in the Designer but in the Method InitDevice at Top. Afterwards i set the Bounds of the Form to the Screen Bounds and that's it. Now it exactly works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Direct3D uses the world coordinate system, and `GetWindowRect` gets a screen coordinate. That's the problem.

Draw Line with another method instead, such as, [`Graphics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?view=netframework-4.8) class:

```
Graphics g;
g = this.CreateGraphics();
Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red);
myPen.Width = 1;
g.DrawLine(myPen, point1x, point1y, point2x, point2y);
```

In addition, regardless of the problem, the code line in your link:

```
SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,(IntPtr)(GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) ^ WS_EX_LAYERED ^ WS_EX_TRANSPARENT));
```

if what you want is style additions, you should:

```
SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,(IntPtr)(GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT));
```